# Disable mouse wheel zoom in Mapbox maps?

Tags: maps, mapbox

How can I disable mouse wheel zoom on Mapbox maps?

I am trying to create a simple map, as per [the simple example](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/examples/):

```
mapbox.auto('map', 'examples.map-vyofok3q');
```

[The Mapbox docs say](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.7/#mapbox.map) that you can supply an extra eventhandler argument when you create the map, including the MM.MouseWheelHandler() event, but they do not example how to actually provide a handler:

```
eventHandlers can be an array of event handlers, including any of the following:
.... MM.MouseWheelHandler()
```

Please could someone give an example of how to use this handler to disable mouse wheel zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this is a double with a support forum question, but I'll write it here as well)-> http://bl.ocks.org/4404508

Answer (score 1):

For Mapbox GL JS maps

```
map.scrollZoom.disable();
```